# Want to run two separate Pipeline from .gitlab-ci.yml file against two separate branches for deploying into two separate aws accounts

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab, gitlab-ci, aws-cli, gitlab-ci-runner

I have all pipeline against aws "A" account for all branches. Now I want to run pipeline for aws "B" accounts against master branch only and rest of branch pipeline will trigger the aws "A" account. Please guide me to how I configure pipeline to run aws "cli" commands against two accounts from same .gitlab-ci.yml file. Just want to host some files into s3 thru "aws s3" cli commands.

Regards
Aniket

Answer (score 0):

Include `only:refs` and `except:refs` inside .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
job_for_master_only:
  only:
    refs:
      - master
  script:
      - command_for_B_account

job_for_other_branches:
  except:
    refs:
      - master
  script:
      - command_for_A_account
```

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyrefsexceptrefs

### Edit after comment

If the commands are the same with only different configurations, then you can use job template. A job template needs to have a name that start with a '.'. Use `extends` keyword to utilize the template:

```
.job_template:
  script:
    - some_command_that_use_environment_variable_ACCOUNT_ID

job_for_master_only:
  extends:
    - .job_template
  only:
    refs:
      - master
  variables:
    ACCOUNT_ID: B

job_for_other_branches:
  extends:
    - .job_template
  except:
    refs:
      - master
  variables:
    ACCOUNT_ID: A
```

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends

Comment: Commands are same for both account, just the value got change according to environment. Commands are related to "aws cli commands" for s3. I want to ask how do I configure different different aws profile for separate account to deploy into different account s3 bucket.

Comment: @Aniket I've edited my answer to cater your scenario